# Can I throttle tar without ionice?

Tags: amazon-ec2, software-raid, tar, rate-limiting, ionice

My tar command

```
tar --remove-files -cvif 2011-08-02_14-05-09.tar 2011-08-02_14-05-09
```

Writes 80MB/s. That's beyond the capacity we can spare because MySQL starts queuing up writes and eventually we get monitoring alerts cause systems won't wait forever on MySQL and time out.

Q: Can I throttle `tar` to only do 20MB/s?

Didn't find anything in the manpage and we already tried with the lowest `ionice` class: `/usr/bin/ionice -c3 tar <...>` but that doesn't impact the MBs written/s and MySQL still freezes up.

Maybe `ionice` is ignored because we're on a `/dev/md0` software RAID device?

Comment: I guess as a hack we could immediately let tar bzip the archive cause we do have CPU cycles to spare. But I'm really interested to see if I can cap IO in a solid manner.

Comment: `ionice` not working for you may have been because you were running with the incorrect scheduler.  It apparently only works with the CFQ scheduler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ratepipe](http://code.google.com/p/ratepipe/).

I downloaded and tried it out and it seems to DTRT. It should work for you:

```
tar --remove-files -cvif - 2011-08-02_14-05-09 | ratepipe -r 20 > 2011-08-02_14-05-09.tar
```

Comment: Great idea! I found an alternative called `pv` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) that can be found in apt. 
Syntax would become

    `tar --remove-files -cvif - 2011-08-02_14-05-09 | pv -L 20m > 2011-08-02_14-05-09.tar`

Can also e.g. show a progress bar

Comment: That's it! I knew there was a sexier program around, but couldn't remember `pv`.

Comment: This is a gem of a find.  Thanks.  `ratepipe` rocks.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write the tar to stdout (using *-f -*) and pipe it into something that throttles. I'll see if I can find something quickly.

Since tar will not buffer much, it should wait on the reads.

Edit: MikeB beat me to it: ratepipe will do.