# Best way remove old log without blocking cpu

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, remove

I have 3 AWS EC2 machines, using each 500G of EBS storage.
On them I have SolrCloud search engine running on Jetty, and serving lots of queries.
In time the jetty logs have grwn hugely, up to ~200G in size.
I would like to remove that, but without giving up availability of my solr system.
If i do `rm -rf logfile` then CPU wait goes up to 99% and the nodes on that machines are not responding anymore, until the load decreases.

Is there a way to remove those log files without this huge load increase?
Thanks

Later Edit:
So, i've found online 4 ways of emptying big files, but there is no comparation between, so i'm not sure which satisfies my problem. Pros and cons for each of them?

```
1.> largefile.txt
2. truncate -s 0 {filename.txt}
3. logrotate
4. cat /dev/null > largefile.txt
```

Comment: `: > logfile` will zero the file...

Comment: @ewwhite thanks! would this be light on the CPU?

Comment: @ewwhite i've also found this articlehttp://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/truncate-large-text-file-in-unix-linux/ but it says nothing on CPU performance

Comment: Test these approaches in *your* environment.

Comment: On a Unix/Linux system truncating a file (by any of the means described) still leaves the data on the disk - and the application with the open handle will continue to write to the shadow file (that's why logrotate uses a script which usually includes sending a signal to the server to close and re-open it's log files).

Answer (score 1):

You could try limiting the amount of CPU that the rm process can use. It will take longer to run but it won't swamp your system. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/) is an article talking about that using a program called cpulimit.

Answer (score 1):

the problem might not even be the CPU, but IOLOAD.

i had the issue with a few > 20GB sized Logfiles some time ago.

basically what i did to reduce the impact of the removal:

```
nice -n19 ionice -c3 rm LOGFILE
```

ionice however might not work correctly for your hardware setup and/or io scheduler settings.

According to Stu Thompson you might need the CFG scheduler for a working ionice command.

> ionice not working for you may have been because you were running with the incorrect scheduler. It apparently only works with the CFQ scheduler. –  Stu Thompson Oct 31 '11 at 12:28

See this for the [ionice CFG scheduler issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/296686/can-i-throttle-tar-without-ionice)